# Java Spring controller response not being converted to JSON

Tags: java, json, spring-mvc, controller, httpresponse

I have the following method:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/products/{productId}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public ProductDTO getProductById()...{

//return populated ProductDTO.

}
```

ProductDTO have the following structure:

```
public class ProductDTO implement Serializable{
String id;
Double price;
Color color;
}
-----

public class Color implements Serializable {

String name;
String RgbValue;

}
```

The problem here is that the Color attribute isn't being marshalled:
The JSON that I get in the response is the following:

```
{
"id" : "V6 Motor"
"price" : "616$"
"color" : "com.test.src.data.Color@16b7656b"
}
```

Why the Color isn't being marshalled ?

Comment: do you have getters and setters in ProductDTO?

Comment: yes , I have all getters and setters

Comment: What is your JSON library? Maybe its not capable of converting 'complex' properties

Comment: Show us your MVC configuration (specifically the parts for JSON serialization).

Comment: I've inherited a lot of xml configuration code , how its named the part of the JSON serialization  (I'll find it) ?

Comment: Look for an `ObjectMapper`, `MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter`, `GsonHttpMessageConverter`.

Comment: I've tried to return directly the Color instead the ProductDTO and it worked , so it seems that there is a problem converting complex properties inside a complex property.

Comment: Try to include `Jackson` library in your `pom.xml` and see

Comment: Could you show how the `ProductDTO` is instantiated? It seems you are using Spring Boot, and it is going to deserialize the object to JSON string automatically if your method is annotated by `@ResponseBody`. BTW, the type of `price` is `Double`, how you get it as `String` in response?

Answer (score -2):

try to override the toString method for Color because i think Spring is trying to treat it as a string